# Htaccess: Rewrite index.rss to index.php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL:
I want this URL below

```
www.test.com/search/test.rss?query=keyword
```

to get sent to the below URL **without** rewriting the URL in the browser. Also notice the domain is different.

```
www.newdomain.com/search/test.php?query=keyword
```

In other words, when someone goes to the first URL, the query will be sent to test.php. The extension has to be .rss (so don't suggest changing that) due to some temporary hack.

Comment: Are those domains being served by the same Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/test.rss search/test.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's rewriting the URL though. Is there a way for the URL in the browser to remain the same? ie /search/test.rss ? I forgot to mention the domain I want to rewrite to is also different.

Comment: It shouldn't redirect at all/show in the browser any different if it's the above, however you can't do it to a different site without redirecting fully no